# Windows Update Online with Proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, updates

I'm looking for a solution to get Windows updates online behind a proxy. I know that Windows Update is using the winhttp proxy instead of the wininet proxy. If I set this proxy with the command `netsh winhttp set proxy myproxy:8080` the client gets his online updates. 
The issue is that these clients are used sometimes in the office and sometimes outside of the office. So if I would set the winhttp proxy with the command above the client wouldn't get any updates outsite of the office.

Could you help me with a best practices for this issue? An alternative would be a possiblity to configure Windows Update to use the wininet proxy or to tell the clients that they use the WSUS if they are internal and online updates when they are external.

Many Thanks

Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Group Policy editor (`gpedit.msc`), go to
`Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update`.

The option
[Specify Intranet Microsoft update service location](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wu-settings#specify-intranet-microsoft-update-service-location)
allows to point computers to an internal Microsoft update service location, while
the option
[Do not connect to any Windows Update Internet locations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wu-settings#do-not-connect-to-any-windows-update-internet-locations) 
can restrict updates to just that internal update service.

Even when Windows Update is configured to receive updates from an intranet update service, it will periodically retrieve information from the public Windows Update service to enable future connections to Windows Update, and other services like Microsoft Update or the Windows Store.

For more information see the Microsoft article
[Manage additional Windows Update settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wu-settings).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then our Windows 10 Clients will get Upgrades when they are external, right? I know there is a policy to defer the upgrades but if we set this policy our WSUS shows "not applicable" to every update (see [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c96747ab-47d8-4e5b-a970-29057bcd93fc/windows-10-updates-are-quotnot-applicablequot-for-versions-1607-1703-1709?forum=winserverwsus#8e36cf2a-4445-4403-b416-1c3bd1798f9a)).

Comment: This might help : [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/803626/correct-gpo-setting-to-use-internal-wsus-with-ms-update-servers). Ensure also that all 3 service locations specify `http://wsusServer:8530` and also in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate` item `UpdateServiceUrlAlternate`.